# Add a <div class="thumbnail">..</div>

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

This is part of my code.

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
            </div>  

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://goo.gl/an2HXY">   
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://goo.gl/Av1pac">
              </div>
              <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://goo.gl/vw43v1">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://goo.gl/0Kd7UO">
          </div>
        </div>        
  </div>
```

I keep getting this error. `(title)`

This is a tutorial from codeaccademy.
Instructions:

1.Inside the second .. column, add two thumbnails. Use "http://goo.gl/Av1pac" for the first image and "http://goo.gl/vw43v1" for the second image.

2.Inside the third column, add just one thumbnail. Use "http://goo.gl/0Kd7UO" for the image.

3.In the preview window, click the "Full Screen" button to see the results.

Comment: You have not closed the first div having class `col-md-4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
        </div>  

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/an2HXY">   
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/Av1pac">
          </div>
          <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/vw43v1">
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/0Kd7UO">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Basically the first "col-md-4"-classed div is not closed, which is the reason you are getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

your first div (.col-md-4) is not closed, maybe that is the problem?
(after the .thumbnail div).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
        </div>  

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://goo.gl/an2HXY">   
        </div>
     </div>  <!-- add this to close the first col-md-4 -->
```